# CakePHP 3 Ajax script work in view but not in external script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm using CakePHP 3 and the following script to call a controller

```
$('.link_like').click(function(event) {

    event.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).data('value');

    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: '/instatux/like-'+id +'',
        success: function(data){
            $('#compteur_like-' +id +'')
            .append(data);

        },
        error: function(data)
        {
            alert('fail');
        }
    });
});
```

This script works perfectly when he is inside a view but i want to use it as an external script , a .js file in the js folder 
but I get an error 500 without further details.

Did i miss something or any cakephp configuration ?

I have some others script in the js folder and he works good.

Comment: If the only difference is the location of the script then it might be the "url" parameter which isn't right. Check your error logs to find the reason for the 500 error response. Without these logs it's like walking with your eyes closed.

Comment: thanks for the answer but the only thing i have in my log is that i didn't create the view add.ctp but i dont need to have it, it should work without

Comment: `$this->autoRender= false` or `exit();` at the end of function

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment, I think you are facing the problem for not created add.ctp file.

If you don't want to create add.ctp file. In your controller you should use

```
$this->autoRender = false;
```

Comment: it finally work by calling the script before the </body> ! but i want to use it on another page it worked one time and after a refresh he doesn't work       Do i need to use another script because of a potential conflict with the ID for the .js ?

Comment: Every thing is working, i'v just forget to pass an ID to the link in the other page , thanks everyne :)